# Is it possible to put the add-filter()-hook into a function?

Tags: filters, email

for my plugin with a lot of different features, I want to realize a mail-function to send HTML-mails. For this I have to add a filter-Hook like this:

```
function set_content_type($content_type){
    return 'text/html';
}
```

and two filter-hooks:

```
add_filter('wp_mail_content_type','set_content_type');
remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );
```

Can I put this two hooks inside my mail function?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course:

```
function my_mail()
{

    add_filter('wp_mail_content_type','set_html_content_type');

    wp_mail();

    remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );

}
```